# I need a substring from JsonPath

Tags: jsonpath

The given string is:

```
{"POWER":"ON","Dimmer":2,"Color":"12345678","HSBColor":"120,100,2","Channel":[0,1,0,0]}
```

result should be:
`123456`

In the Android app MQTT Dash I need only the first six characters from the color.

With `$.Color` I get:

> Invalid color format

Answer (score 0):

I did the following for a sonoff/trasmota color bulb:

1) Leave blank the field "Extract from JSON Path"

2) on the event "On Receive", write the following code:

```
event.payload = JSON.parse(event.payload)['Color'].substring(0,6);
```

Hope this helps.

Cheers.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. As far as I have tried, I need to prepend a '#' before the color code. Please confirm this.